# Cant play live stream(m3u8) using hls.js, flashls, jw player

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming, hls

I am trying to livestream a `.m3u8` using these web video player but can't get them to work. What am I missing?
This link is working fine in vlc on both PC and Android.
Link:http://mumsite.cdnsrv.jio.com/jiotv.live.cdn.jio.com/Aaj_Tak/Aaj_Tak_800.m3u8
(It's an Indian news channel)

I tried it on:

> [www.hlsplayer.net/](http://www.hlsplayer.net/)
>
> [video-dev.github.io/hls.js/demo/](http://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/demo/)
>
> [www.flashls.org/latest/examples/chromeless/](http://www.flashls.org/latest/examples/chromeless/)
>
> [www.flashls.org/latest/examples/osmf/GrindPlayer.html](http://www.flashls.org/latest/examples/osmf/GrindPlayer.html)
>
> [www.flashls.org/latest/examples/osmf/StrobeMediaPlayback.html](http://www.flashls.org/latest/examples/osmf/StrobeMediaPlayback.html)

What am I missing? Is there something wrong with the link? (I intercepted it with burp.) Help Please.

Comment: On the web, additional restrictions (like Cross Origin Resource Sharing) are relevant. Additionally, the content is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

This link is working fine on chrome on android 6(i just tested it).
the hlsplayer.net is also playing that link in chrome..

the task you want to complete here is actually in 2 TWO part.

1. Website must be able to fetch that stream.
2. The video plugin which is used by website to play video must be supported by your browser.

Some website uses old Flash Plugin and modern browser uses HTML5 video tag.

just look at this.

http://mobilehtml5.org/

So any new browser with html5 engine will be able to play it.

if website uses Flash plugin and browser don't then you can't play video from that website.
if your browser (or android version  )is old then you cant play it in browser.

Playing this link in Dedicated player is different than playing it on web browser.
done...